# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' Return code 1 for dex process

Tags: java, android, assembly, transform

Using Asm to inject a class all method

Here is my code :

transform api get all class

```
def cacheFile = new File(file.parent, file.name + ".cache");
fis = new FileInputStream(file)
fos = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile)
println "injectFile: ${file.path}"
byte[] bytes = hackClass(file, null, false, fis);
fos.write(bytes)

if (file.exists()) {
   file.delete()
 }
cacheFile.renameTo(file)
```

Asm method visiter

```
  @Override
  public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
    MethodVisitor mv = null;

    if(name.equals("onCreate") || name.equals("onPause")){
        System.out.println(file.getName() + "Method name : " + name);
        mv = cv.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
        return new TraceMethodVisitor(name, mv);
    }

    if (cv != null){
        mv = cv.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
    }

    return mv;
}
```

MethodVisitor code:

```
@Override
public void visitCode() {
    //add start
    mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
    mv.visitLdcInsn("========start=========");
    mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);

    mv.visitLdcInsn("Hi");
    mv.visitLdcInsn("hello world");
    mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "android/util/Log", "v", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I", false);

    super.visitCode();
}
```

**if MethodVisitor just modify one method, success**

**modify two or more methods, fail**, above code modify two methods

Below is the output from the console:

```
  :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
  Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException:stack: overflow
  Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException:stack: overflow

  2 errors; aborting
  :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  * What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process

How can I fix this issue? :(

Comment: add  multiDexEnabled true in default config file of build.gradle like this
`defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
       }`
and you can add compile file : 
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

Comment: unuseful, maybe transform can not use multidex, new error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> proguard.KeepClassSpecification.<init>(ZZZZZZLproguard/ClassSpecification;)V

Answer (score 0):

Create class com/bigocto/hacksourcecode/JavaInjectTest

```
public class JavaInjectTest {

  public static void test1(){
    //Do something what you want
  }
  public void test2(){
    System.out.println("I am test 2");
  }
}
```

modify MethodVisitor code

```
 @Override
public void visitCode() {
    //add start

    this.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, "com/bigocto/hacksourcecode/JavaInjectTest", "test1", "()V", false);

    super.visitCode();
}
```

issue be sovled !!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue with similar error :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
```

In my case error was including dependency with Java 1.8 bytecode causes build to fail as my application was using Java 1.7.

I raised same with library maintainers and by explicitly adding following line to library's module level build.gradle fixed the issue:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

hope it helps.